# Watermark Textbox cleared on partial postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel, watermark

when my page loads very first time i see the watermark on the textbox but if any postback on the page, the watermark is cleared, is there a way to hold that watermark on the textbox?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            $("#txtEmail").watermark("Email Address");
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Email Invalid"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: When people ask questions like this, I always wonder: are they familiar with browser developer tools like Firebug (built in to Chrome)?  It would be very easy to use Firebug to see exactly what is happening here.

Comment: i do familiar with firebug and i have no idea how would you see exactly what is happening when you click the button, and i do understand the firebug for checking the stylsheets and stuffs... if you know then please let me know.

Comment: 1) go to the **Scripts** section in Firebug.  2) select your HTML file  in the drop-down.  3) add a breakpoint on the line $("txtEmail").watermark.  4) Debug using the console (check that the selector is successful, etc)

Comment: thanks for the tip, can you post this as an answer. i able to find what was the cause.

Comment: Why don't you share the problem, so others can find this useful, otherwise it's a lesson on debugging with Firebug.

Comment: Rick: the problem was that selector was not selected and the reason for that is because i was using `<asp:updatepanel...` and i have to figured out how to make it work with asp:updatepanel which is a different subject. hope this helps you.

Comment: All good, just wanted to clean up my answer for others, I was pretty sure this was due to an UpdatePanel, hence the pageLoad function in my answer.

Comment: `pageLoad()` will load without calling explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to the Scripts section in Firebug.
2. select your HTML file in the drop-down.
3. add a breakpoint on the line $("txtEmail").watermark.
4. Debug using the console (check that the selector is successful, etc)

Answer (score 2):

```
 //for jquery ready
 $(function () {
      $("#<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>").watermark("Email Address");
 });

 //for partial postbacks 
 function pageLoad()
 {
      $("#<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>").watermark("Email Address");
 }
```

Comment: its clearing the textbox watermark after it does a postback so i wonder how to handle

Comment: what server code you talking? any postback there is no code attach to it, if any postback the postback would be dropdownlist indexchanged or click a button

Comment: You need to show us the code you are using, all of it on the page and code-behind, to solve your problem.