# ASP.NET button click clears jQuery watermark

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, watermark

I am using [jQuery watermark plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) to apply watermark on my ASP.NET text boxes. The textbox also has ASP.NET validations attached to it. When I click on any button on the page, the watermark disappears. Interesting part is, watermark appears when I take focus on the textbox and then take the focus away from it. So, button click made the watermark invisible.

Can anyone find why this occurs?

Comment: Why don't you use placeholder?

Comment: I'd try this: [Watermark Textbox cleared on partial postback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10308152/1316573)

Comment: @Kuzgun, I am not using placeholder as users are still using older browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Usage Notes:](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/#Important_usage_notes)

> Form submission - The plugin automatically cleans up all watermarks
>   prior to form submission, so you should never need to manually remove
>   watermarks before submit.

In other words, this is by design. The feature is so you don't accidentally post the watermark and mistake it as entered data.

You can see by the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/source/browse/trunk/jquery-watermark/jquery.watermark/jquery.watermark.js) starting at line 425, it provides the following explanation:

> // In order to reliably clear all watermarks before form submission,
>   // we need to replace the form's submit function with our own
>   // function.  Otherwise watermarks won't be cleared when the form
>   // is submitted programmatically.

This is why any postback, full or partial, would result in the watermark being cleared. (Any postback submits the form.)

If you want the watermark to display again, for a partial postback, you will need to reload it. (`$.watermark.showAll();`)

Comment: I tried calling $.watermark.showAll() in the update panel and also on page load, but no luck. Where should it be placed?

Comment: Add `function pageLoad() {$.watermark.showAll();}` to your javascript. This will be called every time your page posts back. Here's a short article that talks about this: [Simplify ASP.NET AJAX client-side initialization](http://encosia.com/simplify-aspnet-ajax-client-side-page-initialization/)